# Printing line-drawing chars from dosemu

Tags: 14.04, printing

I'm running an old DOS office suite under `dosemu` in Ubuntu 14.04. Everything seems to work fine except that I can't manage to print the line-drawing characters which form part of the cp437 character set characteristic of DOS.

I am able to to print to my USB printer and also to the cups-pdf printer, but in both cases these special characters appear as others with accents and umlauts, obviously from a different character set.

In the `dosemu` configuration file, `.dosemurc` which I copied to my home directory, I set the following:

```
$_external_char_set = "utf8"
$_internal_char_set = "cp437"
```

If I save the office file to a text file within `dosemu`, the characters appear correctly if I use EDIT. Then from Ubuntu, I can use `iconv` to convert the character set, but this is not the best solution as then I can't print any graphics characters which might be in the original file.

*Does anyone have any ideas how I can fix my character set problems?*

Answer (score 2):

Wow!  Trip down to memory lane...

This is a typical PC-DOS problem that was never *decently* solved on DOS either.  This depended (and apparently still depends) entirely on your *printer* supporting cp437...

The only way I ever solved this problem 25 years ago was to use the IBM ProPrinter or the Tandy DMP-80 as those were one of the few printers that supported cp437.

That being said, *depending on the DOS application you're using*, you might still find printers (Epson comes to mind) that wrote "drivers" for some of the applications (Lotus 1-2-3 comes to mind) that did a simple translation of the cp437 to their internal character set.

(Epson *never* solved the problem of the line drawing characters *in a decent way*, so don't run out and buy one of them right now!)

Comment: And as you're a reputation 1 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Comment: Michael, if you would have *additional questions* about computer archaeology, I'd be happy to help.  Just post a new question and add a comment "@Fabby: Computer archaeology". ;-) There are a few old farts like us on this site and I'm pretty sure some of them will butt in too!

Comment: Hi, same issue though occurs when I print to cups-pdf to generate a pdf file. If I could just print to pdf with the charset conversion taking place correctly, I would be happy. Since the dosemu configuration file apparently has configuration options for indicating the internal and external charsets, it seems that this issue should be resolved or I am missing something.

Comment: I'm not saying it cannot be solved! I'm saying that this was: DOS, Printer AND application dependent. I don't know how old you are or what your background is, but in the case of `dosemu` you have to add the emulator to the mix.  If the above answer does not meet your requirements, please downvote and I'll delete it.

Comment: Thank for your help, but I'm still convinced it's a dosemu configuration or bug issue. I'll try getting some help in their mailing lists.